# Opaque background Toolbar when scrolling

Tags: swiftui, uikit, toolbar

I have opaque the background of the TabBar but not the ToolBar when I expected both...

```swift
.onAppear{
    let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
    tabBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance
    let toolBarApperance = UIToolbarAppearance()
    toolBarApperance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    UIToolbar.appearance().standardAppearance = toolBarApperance
    UIToolbar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = toolBarApperance
  }
```

Some hint plis ;)

Answer (score 0):

`toolbarBackground(_:for:)` solves the problem but only in iOS 16

```swift
if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
  ...
  .toolbarBackground(Color.black, for: .automatic)
}
```